# Case sensitive sybase query: Invalid column name

Tags: database, sybase, sap-ase

Details:

- 2 databases: sybase version 15 and sybase version 16
- 1 table each (identical): AuthRole with columns id, **rolename** and description
- Tried both jTDS and jconn drivers

Query:

```
SELECT t1.roleName FROM AuthRole t1;
```

Results:

- Sybase 15: rows returned successfully. 'roleName' could be upper, lower or a mix of case, i.e. not case sensitive
- Sybase 16: **Invalid column name** 'roleName'. It will only work with 'rolename' which is the exact case of the column. Anyone know why this would happen and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If on ASE 15 both queries work - with "rolename" and "roleName" - that means the the sort order in this database is case insensitive.

If on ASE 16 "rolename" is different than "roleName" - that means the the sort order in this database is case sensitive.

You can check this by querying:

```
if "a" = "A" print "Case insensitive" else print "Case sensitive"
```

This setting is set and static for the whole server (and for all the databases that the server contains), but can be changed. Of course changing the sort order is a time consuming process, as it requires to rebuild all indexes based on character types.

You can check the server sortorder setting:

```
exec sp_configure 'sortorder id'
```

The information about sort order should be visible in the ASE errorlog when the database server starts:

```
00:0002:00000:00002:2017/07/04 16:49:26.35 server  ASE's default unicode sort order is 'binary'.
00:0002:00000:00002:2017/07/04 16:49:26.35 server  ASE's default sort order is:
00:0002:00000:00002:2017/07/04 16:49:26.35 server   'bin_iso_1' (ID = 50)
00:0002:00000:00002:2017/07/04 16:49:26.35 server  on top of default character set:
00:0002:00000:00002:2017/07/04 16:49:26.35 server   'iso_1' (ID = 1).
```

In my example the sort order is binary - which is case sensitive.

Information how to change the sort order for the server is in the [ASE manual](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc31654.1600/doc/html/san1360629216676.html). Basicaly to change the sort order you need to:

- add the new sort order using the charset program,
- change the config parameter 'sortorder id'
- reboot the ASE server (the server boots, rebuilds the disk devices and then it shuts down)
- reboot the ASE server again
- indexes that are build on character types are marked as invalid and need to be rebuild

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like an issue with the sort order, eg:

- ASE 15 is configured with a case-insensitive sort order
- ASE 16 is configured with a case-sensitive sort order

You should be able to confirm the above by running `sp_helpsort`.

In ASE, case (in)sensitivity applies to data as well as identifiers (eg, table/column names).

To get ASE 16 to function like ASE 15, the DBA will need to change the sort order in the ASE 16 dataserver (I'd suggest they also verify the character set while they're at it).

Keep in mind that changing the sort order (and/or character set) is a dataserver-wide configuration and will require (at a minimum) a rebuild of all indexes and re-running of `update index statistics`. [For more info the DBA should refer to the ASE `System Administration Guide`, Chapter on `Configuring Character Sets, Sort Orders and Languages`.]

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head:

In older versions of Sybase ASE you had to carefully set the case-sensitivity at server installation time.  The installer defaults to case-sensitive. Maybe the admin who installed ASE15 noticed this (and changed the default to case-insensitive), whereas the admin who installed your ASE16 didn't.

Yes, case-Sensitivity is a property of the Server. You can change it at a later time with `sp_configure` or ALTER DATABASE, or both (I don't remember and I don't have the time to look it up). You can also use a graphical admin tool to change the server default sort order.

In any case  only databases *created after* that configuration change will be affected. Confusingly, older databases will still be case-sensitive, or lots of warnings will be issued. This is because in your older tables, all primary keys (PK)  are implemented as indices, in assume case-sensitivity, and PKs and the PK indices cannot be changed by an installer or a config wizard. 
In fact, you have to drop and re-create the indices and run `dbcc something` (again I don't remember).

For small databases, this drop-and-recreate of indices can of cause be done (use a script or a database reengineering tool to do so). For larger databases this can take some time.

Maybe it's different for ASE16 -check the docuemntation